# How to create login authentication in whootin using oAuth 2.0?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I created an app in [whootin.com](http://whootin.com) and I have

- Consumer Key
- Consumer Secret
- Request Token URL
- Access Token URL
- Authorize URL

I want to authenticate user those who are having whootin account and display their information in my site.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Because OAuth is only a specification, there are a lot of differenct clients you can use. For example: https://github.com/vznet/oauth_2.0_client_php.